# Campaign UTM Tracking through to form

Tags: cookies, querystring, analytics

My client has asked that I track and send campaign information through a contact form.

So basically a user might come to the site on this type of URL:

```
domain.com/?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=paid16-03-2022
```

I can certainly get the query string information into a form (if they come directly to the form page) but if they go to multiple other pages and then fill in the form it gets a little more difficult to track.

My thinking was to:

- Set a cookie to capture the query string variables when they come to the site
- Put these cookie variables into a hidden contact form field/s  (if they go to this page)

I just wanted to double-check if this is the best way, if anyone had done this before or if there was a plugin or something else to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like that. I built something very similar a few months ago where I checked for a query parameter in the URL when the page loaded, created a cookie with it using the Cookies plugin so I could access it in twig, then appended that query parameter to a donation button on other pages.

Cookies: https://plugins.craftcms.com/cookies

You also need to check if the parameter has changed or disappeared, and update or replace your cookie value accordingly. Some of the code I used is below.

_layout.twig:

```
{# User Tracking #}
    {% if craft.app.request.getParam('s_src')|length %}
        {# If a user lands on the site with s_src in the URL, set a variable to track them throughout the site #}
        {% set s_src = craft.app.request.getParam('s_src') %}

        {# Use that variable to set a cookie, which will track them between pages #}
        <script>
            document.cookie = "userSrc={{ s_src }}; Path=/; expires={{ now|date_modify('+1 day')|date('l, d-M-Y H:i:s T') }}";
        </script>
    {% else %}
        {# If there isn't an s_src param in the URL, clear the variable, but still define it so Craft doesn't crash #}
        {% set s_src = '' %}
    {% endif %}
```

content block:

```
{# If there's an s_src param in the URL, use that. If there isn't, check for the cookie and use that. If there isn't one, use the defaultSessionVariable #}
<a href="{{ block.button.url }}{{ '?' in block.button.url == 0 ? '?' }}&s_src={% if s_src|length %}{{ s_src }}{% elseif getCookie('userSrc') %}{{ getCookie('userSrc') }}{% else %}{{ block.defaultSessionVariable }}{% endif %}" class="bg-{{ block.buttonColor }} c-white btn-lg button-block" aria-label="{{ block.button.text }}" target="{{ block.button.target }}">{{ block.button.text }}</a>
```

If you're in the UK, Europe or California, you'll need to comply with the GDPR / CCPA legislation on cookies.

Comment: Thanks Daryl, thats fantastic - I will give it a try shortly